# Unable to upload my photo while applying for an Indian e-Visa. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: visas, india

Anyone know which browser or what to do to upload the photo in the [India e-visa](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html) process? In the form, the popup to upload the photo is working but after it closed the main form is not showing the photo and I can't continue the application.

I've tried with latest Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge, but nothing is working. I tried to reach help desk information (from the website) without success.

Comment: Try Internet Explorer. I remember having problems a while ago with an Indian visa Web site in Chrome (though I’m not sure it was specifically to do with uploading the photo) but it worked in IE.

Comment: Make sure your picture has the correct dimensions.

Comment: I ran into this even though my photo was cropped to the right dimensions and was in the right file format. I tried what Maddy suggested above and it worked! Just have to crop the image slightly smaller using the crop tool during upload, and you can proceed past the photo upload screen. Now if only they could fix this very weird and confusing bug

Comment: Since I just realized this from my own visa application and just in case it is of use to somebody else :) The site does not correctly process filenames that contain dots. I had a filename containing a date (e.g. "2018.12.20 Portrait.jpeg"). And it was rejected with a "only jpg and jpeg allowed" despite being the correct size, format, etc. "Portrait.jpeg" worked.

Comment: If you use Adobe Photoshop -> Export As -> JPG -> Make sure uncheck "embed color profiles".

Comment: Can confirm, unchecking the "embed color profiles" in Photoshop worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I resolved with the same width and height (for example 500 pixels width and 500 pixels height), the photo crop tool provided by the web site is unhelpful and it doesn't throw error or anything.

Thank you.

Comment: "I resolved with the same width and height" - I don't understand what you mean by that.  If you can explain in more detail what you did, it will be more helpful to other people with the same problem.

Comment: @NateEldredge My travel agent told me that the photo has to be 5,5cm by 5,5cm - so same width and height, different from most other passport photo formats I know - and the site will not accept anything else. Maybe that is what they meant with this answer?

Comment: Yes, width and height need to be the same, also in order to be accepted, your shoulders need to be inside the frame (not just the head).

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget everyone, make sure the self image you upload has the exact same pixel length both horizontally and vertically for the image to upload correctly for the e-tourist visa. Otherwise it will not work. Such a common problem amongst travellers.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from following:

- The aspect ratio of 1:1 (min of 200 pixel & max of 900 pixel in width and height) for applicant image
- 1:3 (min of 67 pixels & a max of 300 in height, and a min of 200 pixel & max of 900 pixel in width) for signature image
- Keeping the file in size limit under 200 KB

Make sure to do not have any periods (full stop `.`) in your file name. If you have a full stop in your file name of the image, rename it without that and try uploading again. It should work.

Comment: Eliminate all periods in the filename. We tried all of the above suggestions and ultimately this was what fixed the issue.

Comment: I was able to get past this after I had reduced the size of my .jpg file from 503KB to 76KB.

Comment: The periods in the filename were my problem.  If I hadn't found this answer & comments, I never would have known.  The error message didn't say anything about the filename.  Thank you.  (my filename was "Firstname.Lastname.jpg" -- I don't think that is really so strange.  It's 2023 and the website can't parse such a filename???)

Answer (score 3):

One more glitch I ran into: if **your session expires** before you upload your photo (for example, if you need to spend some time scanning it etc), all uploads will silently fail with no error message of any kind, it will just kick you back to the upload page again.  The only hint, and it's a small one, is that the top of the form will say "Application ID:-" instead of having the actual alphanumeric ID.

To fix the issue, navigate back to the home page, retrieve your application again, and the upload form should magically start working.

Answer (score 2):

On a mac you need to do the following with images as even though you think you are within the guidelines, it doesn't seem to work.

- Go to Tools-Adjust Size and adjust the pixels.
  Then go to File-Export (choose JPEG as the format) which allows you to adjust the quality level - pick the lowest and it reduces the size dramatically and will allow you to upload!

Answer (score 2):

My friend had same complaint. After trying everything from different browser to different .jpg and .jpeg format, we used a slightly smaller crop size than the maximum selection offered by the cropping-square and VIOLA!! We could move forward to the passport filling page!!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You seem to be doing fine but you might still find our [tour] helpful -- it only takes a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I have had isssues with uploading the picture, I had to apply for four people.  I was using UK passport size pictures, after cropping and several attempts I was able to upload and complete two applications. I wasted more than five hours doing this.
Rest of the two applicants I used new photographs size 2*2 which slightly bigger than the UK passport pictures. Then the magic happened with no fuss right in the slot, all done in ten minutes. Google chrome works better....than the explorer.